# How do you know if you believe in Allah?

Tags: allah, belief

For the last few months I have been doing a great deal of reading and research about Islam, listening to lectures, and reading through a couple translations of Qur'an. From an intellectual/rational capacity it all makes sense to me. Learning about Islam feels like coming home after a long absence. But I don't really know what it means or what it's like to believe in God. How do you know if you believe in God, or how do you learn to believe?

Comment: I think to believe in Allah means to put what you have learned so far about Islam into action. So you would want to please Allah by obeying Him and avoiding sinful acts and you would wish to come closer to Him and speak to Him by establishing prayers. You would feel love for Allah developing in your heart and you feel happy when you hear recitations of the holy Qur'an or supplications .You thank Him for everything He has given you and when you are in need you only ask Him for help. To learn about Allah intensifies your belief.             https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufKcMpIJpB0

Answer (score 1):

> *There is no god but God. Muhammad is the messenger of God. ([Shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada))*

If you believe that you actually believe in what you said, then you're a believer.

Other definition could be -

> *This world is a prison for the believer and paradise for the non-believer. (Muslim)*

For sure there forms and levels of hypocrisy, e.g. [Qur'an 4:142](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=4&verse=142), you should check them out.

Allah knows the best.